# Good Generic Repository Pattern when not Using Code First

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern

I'm trying to wrap my head around repository pattern and dependency injection concepts for my ASP.NET MVC applications.

I ran across the article [Repository Pattern with Entity Framework](http://dotnetspeak.com/index.php/2011/03/repository-pattern-with-entity-framework/), and really liked how simple the code is. There doesn't appear to be that much code and it's all completely generic. That is, there's no need for multiple repositories for the different objects in the database as most people appear to be doing. This is just what I want.

However, the code is written for code first, which I'm not planning to use.

Questions:

1. Is there a good reason why the same code couldn't be used for applications that don't use code first?
2. Can someone recommend a better approach for my applications that don't use code first? (Keeping in mind that I'm absolutely sold on this generic pattern.)
3. Any other tips to help me move forward?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If I'm not using code first, what other option is there?

Comment: Here's an interesting (though opinionated) post about the genric repository being an anti-pattern. You might not agree but it's a thoughtworthy article anyway: http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2012/03/05/The-Generic-Repository-Is-An-Anti-Pattern.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a repository interface for *any* underlying data store.  You can simply define an interface like so:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    IQueryable<T> GetQueryable<T>();

    void Insert<T>(T item);
}
```

Then, you can implement a class behind this which will implement it.  It doesn't have to be code-first; you can back it with an [`ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx) created from an EDMX file, for example.

The key here is in creating the right *abstraction*.  You can easily do that with an interface, and then implement it however you want behind the scenes.

Because you're using dependency injection, the implementation doesn't matter as much, as long as you've defined the *contract* correctly, the implementation (and testing of it) should be simple.  And if it doesn't work, or you want a different data store altogether, you just tell your dependency injector to use a different implementation, the contract doesn't change.

The same can be said for any abstraction you create; you can have an interface that reads and writes data (like the article you reference does), you just have to pull the abstraction out.

Comment: Thanks. I know the code I referenced doesn't use a UoW pattern, but I'm not sure I understand why it's not a repository. Obviously, a repository needs to allow writing to the database. What "extra write bits" make you consider it not a repository? Also, do you have a recommended repository code for devs who think using multiple repositories is not a good approach?

Comment: @JonathanWood Technically, what things like LINQ-to-Entities returns to you are [data transfer objects](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html), whereas repositories deal with *domain* objects.  Personally, I'm not a stickler, if I have an interface that gives me read-only access to the data-transfer objects, then I'm ok with calling that a repository.

Comment: @JonathanWood Also, there's no reason to have multiple repositories if using an interface like the one I've defined above; you'd only use separate repositories if you have separate underlying data stores; since you're returning `IQueryable<T>` and the type parameter is on the method, you should easily be able to query most anything.

Comment: @JonathanWood Personally, when I need to read *and* write in the same operation (and think about whether or not you *really* have to do that) I have a specific interface that combines the two and a different class implementation from the implementation of the unit-of-work and repository classes; you could have *one* class that implements them all, but you'd then be able to cast from a repository to a unit-of-work, which is a bad thing; if you need read *and* write access, you have to explicitly request it.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing those data transfer objects in the context of Entity Framework, but it sounds like an unnecessary level of complexity to me. At any rate, all the example repositories I've seen use multiple repositories. I'm running out now but will review your reply in more detail later. Thanks again.

Comment: @JonathanWood Note that any object that you return from LINQ-to-Entities, LINQ-to-SQL, etc. are data-transfer objects.  If they *happen* to be your domain objects as well, that's up to you, but generally, it's a bad idea since logic in your classes doesn't get persisted to the data store, just the data.

Comment: @casperOne: great answer but why do you claim a repository is read-only? Is that your experience or a part of common definition? Fowler defines repositories as rw, for example.

Comment: @WiktorZychla You're right.  Let me update the answer to reflect that.  I've always interpreted it as read-only.  Curious though, what is the inverse of unit-of-work then which allows only read-only access?  I'm assuming it's some variant of an [identity map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html)?

Comment: @JonathanWood Updated the answer, I had a limited definition of what a repository is.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this. I think this link will help you most

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/572761/Generic-repository-pattern-using-EF-with-Dependenc

In this link Generic repository pattern is used with dependency injection in MVC project without using code first approach.